# How to save current application state of classes using Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Until now, I only had to store application state of primitive types like int, string, boolean and for that I used `Properties.Settings.Default` object with no problem.

But now I also need to store instances of classes created with `new` keyword.

So my question is how to store these types of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize your object with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) in that way:

```
var p=new Person();
p.FirstName = "Jeff";
p.MI = "A";
p.LastName = "Price";
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
```

Source and full example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

For the complete process - serializing and deserializing - visit this link:

http://sharpertutorials.com/serialization/

**Notes**:

- you have to use the  attribute [[Serializable]](http://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&rct=j&q=attribute%20Serializable%20c#&ei=xLg1TpDlBMnGtAaSw5m5Ag&usg=AFQjCNG8cUrhHDqPUG5sXimmJnMY_xOoWA) (or other, it depends on the serializer) on your class
- try using POCO objects
- depending on your .NET version, consider toughts in this [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/XmlSerializers1.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [msdn: ObjectSerialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx).

You have to read a couple of articles in order to select right serialization mechanism for your objects.

Regards.